#  Google Map location based on address

Tags: android, google-maps

Im using Google Map in my application, it is working fine by providing longitude, latitude.
But how to display the location based on the address string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class in the Android SDK called Geocoder: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

You should be able to get a List of Address, and each Address has its Latitude and Longitude to display on Map. Use the method getFromLocationName()